# How to use react-sortable-hoc

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I am trying to use the component "[react-sortable-how](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc)". I wrote this:

```
<SortableContainer>
    { questions.map((question,index) => (
        <SortableElement key={index}>
            <QuestionForm key={index} question={question} mode="update" betId={this.props.match.params.betId} cb={this.getQuestions} />
        </SortableElement>    
    )) }
</SortableContainer>
```

But I have this error :

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

I am a beginner in React. I don't understand what this message mean. I tried a lot of things without success.

Comment: Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sortable-hoc-starter-o104x95y86)

Comment: can you share the `QuestionForm` component?

Comment: Thanks for the example awran5. It will help me to understand how it works.

Comment: It works fine on y side with this example. thanks on more time awran5.